# Direct Sum of Factors of Minimal Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that the minimal polynomial $m(z)$ of $T$ factors as $m(z) = a(z)b(z)$, where $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ are coprime monic polynomials. Prove that $V=$range$(a(T))\oplus\,$ range$(b(T))$.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. I am aware that if the monic factors $a(z)$ and $b(z)$ where linear, then they would coincide with eigenspaces. It's not so clear to me that as stated this statement should even be true.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{C}[X]$ is a principal ideal domain so $\langle a, b\rangle=\langle \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\rangle=\langle 1\rangle$ where $\langle\rangle$ is the ideal generated in $\Bbb{C}[X]$.  Hence there exist $p,q\in\Bbb{C}[X]$ such that
$$
1=p(x)a(x)+q(x)b(x)\tag{1}
$$
From $(1)$ follows that for all $v\in V$
$$
v=p(T)a(T)v+q(T)b(T)v=a(T)p(T)v+b(T)q(T)v\tag{2}
$$
so $(2)$ shows that $V=\operatorname{range}(a(T))+\operatorname{range}(b(T))$.  To show that the sum is direct, if $v_1,v_2\in V$ such that
$$
v=a(T)v_1=b(T)v_2
$$
then
$$
b(T)v=b(T)a(T)v_1=0\quad a(T)v=a(T)b(T)v_2=0
$$
and from $(2)$ it follows that $v=0$.